# Hacer que php no me notifique error de variable

Tags: php

Me gustaría guardar cierto contenido en una variable `php` pero me tira error porque no he definido esa variable o bueno eso creo es lo que pasa.

Me lanza el error de:

> Unexpected $EOF expecting t_string or t_variable or t_num_string.

Me gustaría saber con que valor inicializarlas o de que manera poder ignorar el error y que no haya problema, soy nuevo en `php`.

**Esta es una parte del código:**

```
  $contenido2 = "<?php requiere('conexion.php');  
  //aqui es donde me lanza el error  $r=$_POST['ress'];
           $sql = 'INSERT INTO T$i VALUES ( '$r' )  ? 
      >";    


   $fpp = fopen('resT' . $i . '.php' , 'w');
       fwrite($fpp, $contenido2);
```

Comment: Qué estás queriendo hacer? Por qué abrís `<?php` dentro de la variable? Sacá el comentario del código porque no se entiende como es el código originalmente.

Comment: Un consejo. Utiliza nombres de variables descriptivas. Cambia `$i` por `$name_tabla`, `$r` por `$nombre_usuario` (por decir algo). Es una cosa simple que a priori no parece importante pero a la larga es fundamental. En este caso es evidente. Pero es algo que te ayuda mucho a comprender el código.

Comment: según parece te has engalletado con las comillas simples y las variables dentro de comillas dobles

Answer (score 0):

Intenta quitar la T que esta antes de la variable i ($i), en tu codigo y poner un punto y coma al final de tu consulta:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO T$i VALUES ( '$r' )';  ?
```

aparte de eso, estas instrucciones no deberian ir dentro de una variable, no se si depronto lo que estas queriendo hacer es "preparar" unas instrucciones dentro de una variable para que al momento de ponerlas en el html con un echo te las ejecute... cosa que igual no creo que funcione de esa manera  es poco practica, intenta mejor separarlo en el php cada instruccion y hacerlo de manera tradicional.

Ah aparte no puedes hacer varias asignaciones de diferentes variables dentro de una variable, por ejemplo cuando tu intentas asignarle a esta variable:

```
$contenido2 = "$r=$_POST['ress']; $sql = 'INSERT INTO $i VALUES ( '$r' );";
```

Ahora suponiendo estos valores para estas variables:

```
$_POST['ress'] = 25;
$i = "miTabla";
$r = "contenido_r"
$sql;
```

Enrealidad estarias guardando algo así:

```
$contenido2 = "contenido_r = 25; null = 'INSERT INTO miTabla VALUES('$r')';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes poner **PHP_EOL** en el fwrite()

Así:

```
$file = fopen("/var/www/html/carpetas/archivo.txt", "w+");
fwrite($file, "Esto es una nueva línea de texto" . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
```